# How to get data into PrimeReact Table

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a table with PrimeReact. For testing I also have add an list. The resulting web page only showes my data items in the list, but not in the table. How do I get also my data into the table? I also use `value="{data}"` but it is not working.

My code snippet:

```
import React from "react";
import { DataTable } from 'primereact/datatable';
import { Column } from 'primereact/column';

function MyTable() {

    let data = 
        [
            { "id": "1" }, { "id": "2" }
        ];
    
    return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <ul>
    {data.map((myItem, i) => (
        <li key={i}>{myItem.id}</li>
    ))}
    </ul>
    
    <DataTable value="{data}">
        <Column field="id" header="id"></Column>
    </DataTable>
    </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default MyTable;
```

Comment: Remove the ticks (") around {data}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont put quotes around the {data}
:D

```
 <DataTable value={data}>
        <Column field="id" header="id"></Column>
    </DataTable>
```

Comment: sometimes it is hard to be a programer :-)

Comment: sometimes the very simple problems are hard to spot :)